# Python doesn't do proper concatenation of string while using with open

Tags: python, gae-python27

I have a simple .txt file with bunch of lines for instance

```
motorola phone
happy cows
teaching
school work
far far north
teaching
hello
```

now all I want to do is read all these strings and print out. So if the line contains teaching I want to print `teaching is awesome`
so here is my code

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as fo:
    for line in fo:
        if "teaching" in line:
            line = line.rstrip('\n') + " is awesome"
            print line
        else:
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

But this is printing

[image]

so what is happening to the rest of the string. Because it is suppose to print teaching is awesome isn't it. Can some one explain this behaviour of python. Thanks

Comment: Its working on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a windows file with `'\r\n'` and `rstrip` is returning `\r` which means the carriage returns to the beggining of the line and being overwritten.

Try `rstrip('\r').rstrip('\n')`

Comment: Or just `rstrip()`. I'll never understand why people limit the stripping to just one kind of space without any apparent reason. More code and more error-prone...

Comment: Actually, you got the order wrong. For `'\r\n'` you'd need to strip `\n` *first*. More error-prone indeed...

Comment: there's no reason to call it twice - `.rstrip('\r\n')` does the same thing (as does `.rstrip('\n\r')`). The characters given to strip/rstrip are treated as a set of possible characters to remove.

Comment: @KingRadical That does *not* do the same thing, as it actually works :-)

Comment: @KingRadical As far as I can see, you're just wrong there. But feel free to elaborate if you disagree.

Comment: The result of `.rstrip('\r\n')` is the same as the result of `.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r')` is the same as the result of `.rstrip('\n\r')`:

`In [9]: a
Out[9]: 'abcd\r\n'

In [10]: a.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r')
Out[10]: 'abcd'

In [11]: a.rstrip('\r\n')
Out[11]: 'abcd'

In [12]: a.rstrip('\n\r')
Out[12]: 'abcd'`

Comment: @KingRadical Yeah but the answer says `rstrip('\r').rstrip('\n')`. Not `rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r')`. You just made that up.

Comment: That was in reference to your comment about stripping `'\n'` first, but okay

Comment: @KingRadical Then it should've addressed me. Also, I had already argued against stripping just one kind of space (at a time) and suggested to do it at once. I said they **would** need to strip `\n` first (if they did it in two steps at all, which was clearly *not* my suggestion). Finally, your `.rstrip('\r\n')` doesn't do the same as `.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r')`, either, as for example the string `'foo\n\r'` shows.

Answer (score 1):

```
rstrip('\r\n')
```

works like a charm. Must mention I'm on a Ubuntu but it works in windows only with `'\n'`  .

Answer (score 0):

To me it works too... but I am using python 3, so I put the round brackets after print... but you used in line 7 and not in line 5... ?!

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as fo:
    for line in fo:
        if "teaching" in line:
            line = line.rstrip('\n') + " is awesome"
            print(line)
        else:
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

and this is the output:

```
motorola phone
happy cows
teaching is awesome
school work
far far north
teaching is awesome
hello
>>>
```